# If $E(X)=0$ then $P(X=0)=1$?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

This is a really stupid question but I really want to know why the following is true. I'm trying to prove something else and I need to know why that last bit is true.

Comment: Are you assuming anything about $X$, like it is non-negative? If not, can you think of a scenario where the expected value is 0, but none of the outcomes are 0?

Comment: When $X$ is normally distributed with mean $0$, isn’t that a counterexample?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that! $X\in L^2$

Comment: So what you're asking is "If the expected value of $X$ is 0, does it mean that its value is always 0?" The answer is no; take any normally distributed RV with mean 0, and you'll get that $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$ but $P(X = 0) \neq 1$.

Comment: @Kylie Why should this make the suggestions above not valid?

Comment: Actually, I'm asking if the expected value of X is zero is it always true that $P(X=0)=1$?

Comment: I think this is incomplete. Please define your random variable first, and whether it is continuous or discrete. There is no law as such which states that if E(X) = 0, then P(X=0) = 1. This will depend entirely on the R.V. and its distribution.

Answer (score 2):

No, Just look at the following p.m.f. $$ p(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}, & \text{if $x=-1$} \\
\frac{1}{2}, & \text{if $x=1$}
\end{cases}$$
Here, the expectation of $p$ is $0$ although $p(0)=0$.

Comment: This is not the pdf since this is discrete distribution. Do you mean p.m.f.?

Comment: @NCh Yes I meant p.m.f. Thanks for the correction. I will correct it.